# Writing and reading a FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE file in Win32

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I am trying to write to and read from a temporary file with Win32 APIs.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void ThrowLastFSError(std::string name, std::filesystem::path path) {
  throw std::filesystem::filesystem_error{
      name, path,
      std::error_code{(int)::GetLastError(), std::system_category()}};
}

int main() {
  HANDLE hfile = NULL;
  try {
    // Create a temporary file
    CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS params{};
    params.dwSize = sizeof(params);
    params.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN;
    params.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE;
    params.lpSecurityAttributes = nullptr;
    params.hTemplateFile = NULL;

    auto path = L"test.txt";

    hfile = ::CreateFile2(
        path,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,        // Open for reading and writing
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,  // Share both of those modes
        CREATE_NEW, &params);

    if (!hfile || hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
      ThrowLastFSError("CreateFile2", path);
    }

    // Write something to it
    char data[] = "hello world\n";
    DWORD bytes_written;
    bool ok =
        ::WriteFile(hfile, data, sizeof(data) - 1, &bytes_written, nullptr);
    if (!ok) ThrowLastFSError("WriteFile", path);

    // Read something from it

    char inbuf[100];
    DWORD bytes_read = 0;
    ::SetFilePointer(hfile, 0, nullptr, FILE_BEGIN);
    ok = ::ReadFile(hfile, inbuf, sizeof(inbuf), &bytes_read, nullptr);
    if (!ok) ThrowLastFSError("ReadFile", path);
    std::cout << "contains: " << std::string_view(inbuf, bytes_read)
              << std::endl;
    // contains: hello world

    //////////////////////////////
    // PROBLEM: ifstream can't open the file
    //////////////////////////////

    ::SetFilePointer(hfile, 0, nullptr, FILE_BEGIN);
    std::ifstream ifs(path);
    if (!ifs.is_open()) ThrowLastFSError("ifstream()", path);
    // ifstream(): The process cannot access the file because it is being used
    // by another process. : "test.txt"

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << ifs.rdbuf();

    ::CloseHandle(hfile);
    return 0;
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    ::CloseHandle(hfile);
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Note that I create the file with:

- `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`, so I can't close the handle and re-open it
- `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`, so I can read and write to the handle
- `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE`, so I can (theoretically) open other handles to it

`WriteFile` and `ReadFile` seem to work fine.

However, trying to open another handle to the file at the same path with e.g. `ifstream` results in an access violation.

How can I open a handle to file, to which I have a currently-open handle, with `ifstream`?

Comment: You didn't check `bytes_read`. I bet it is zero because you are reading past the end of the file

Comment: You're calling `ReadFile` immediately after `WriteFile`, so you are attempting to read past the end of the file. Use `SetFilePointer` to seek back if you want to read what you've just written. I expect `std::ifstream` is failing to open the file because it doesn't specify shared access (even though you are allowing sharing, other users of the file also have to agree to sharing to be able to open it).

Comment: The call to `GetLastError` isn't going to discover reliable information. There are at least two c'tor calls in between the system setting the last error code and `ThrowLastFSError` trying to pick it up. You will need to call `GetLastError` **immediately** after evaluating the conditions under which the respective API call is documented to have set an error code.

Comment: Thanks both. I've fixed and edited the question to focus on the `ifstream` issue. @JonathanPotter looking at the microsoft STL impl, the `ifstream` is opened with `_wfsopen` using `_SH_DENYNO` by default, which [apparently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fsopen-wfsopen?view=msvc-170#remarks) means "Permits read and write access.", so I think it's using the correct sharing mode

Comment: @IInspectable Good point. When I try opening a second handle manually instead of using `ifstream`: `HANDLE hfile2 = ::CreateFile2(path, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                           FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, OPEN_EXISTING,
                           &params);` I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating the file with `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`.

You can't create a second handle to that file unless you specify `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.

This is outlined in the `CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/ns-fileapi-createfile2_extended_parameters) (dwFileFlags section)

> | Flag | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE | The file is to be deleted immediately after all of its handles are closed, which includes the specified handle and any other open or duplicated handles. If there are existing open handles to a file, the call fails unless they were all opened with the FILE_SHARE_DELETE share mode. **Subsequent open requests for the file fail, unless the FILE_SHARE_DELETE share mode is specified.** |

---

So you need to open both handles with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`:

```cpp
// ...
hfile = ::CreateFile2(
        path,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        CREATE_NEW, &params);

// ....

// open a second handle
// MUST specify FILE_SHARE_DELETE
anotherFile = ::CreateFile2(
        path,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        OPEN_EXISTING, nullptr);
// ...
```

unfortunately this is not possible out-of-the-box with C++ iostreams (you can only share read / write access (with `_SH_DENYNO`), but not delete access)

You could work around this limitation however by creating the handle yourself and then jumping through a few hoops to get the handle into the ifstream: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Yn7vG1o5f)

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

// create handle with appropriate sharing flags
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile2(
    L"somefile.txt",
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    nullptr
);

// convert the handle into a c runtime file descriptor
int cHandle = _open_osfhandle(
    reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(hFile),
    _O_TEXT | _O_RDONLY
);

// create a file stream from the file descriptor
FILE* file = _fdopen(
    cHandle,
    "r"
);

// create a filebuf from the filestream
std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char>> fileBuf(file);

// create an ifstream and swap in our filebuf
std::ifstream stream;
stream.rdbuf()->swap(fileBuf);

// use stream to read from the file, e.g.:
std::string str;
stream >> str;
```

---

Keep in mind though that the `ifstream` most likely won't be very happy if you delete the file while it still has a handle to it (which is most likely the reason you need to go through all those hoops to get a handle with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` into an `ifstream`).

So just to be safe i would recommend to make sure that the file doesn't get deleted before the `ifstream` destructs.

Comment: Ah, disappointing but great info! Thanks. Maybe I'll write an `iostream` customization that works with `CreateFile2` with these sharing modes instead of `_wfsopen` with `_SH_DENYNO`

Comment: @MHebes you could maybe work around this by jumping through a few hoops: 1. Create the file with `CreateFile` / `CreateFile2` with the correct sharing modes - 2. Call `_open_osfhandle` to create a c runtime file descriptor from the handle - 3. Call `_fdopen` to get a `FILE*` for the file descriptor - 4. Construct a `std::basic_filebuf` from the `FILE*` [using the public constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/73924c1920af92899f7582cd904ea819b9db35bc/stl/inc/fstream#L174) -

Comment: Then construct an `std::ifstream` and swap in the filebuf, e.g. `std::ifstream stream; stream.rdbuf()->swap(yourPreparedBasicFilebuf);`. Unfortunately those are quite a few hoops you would need to jump through to get it setup - but at that point you should have a fully functional `ifstream` from the given handle.

Comment: @MHebes [Here's a small example](https://godbolt.org/z/Yn7vG1o5f) that demonstrates how it could work. (i unfortunately don't have a windows pc at hand currently so i can't test it)